# Loop through Access Connections and Close Connection

Tags: vba, excel, odbc

I have multiple users accessing an MS Access database through a Query in Excel.

The users can refresh the queries by pressing a button.

If a user refreshes a query and does not close the Excel file afterwards, the MS Access database opens as Read Only.

Is it possible to circumvent this problem by setting the "MaintainConnection" property to False?

I tried the following code:

```
Sub CloseConnections()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each conn in wb.Connection
        conn.MaintainConnection=False
    Next 

End Sub
```

There are multiple Access connections, that's why I loop through all the connections.

Comment: Can post the `mode` section of the connection string, you can try changing this to just `"Mode=Read"`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I don't have a mode specified in the connection string: `DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=S:\path\Data.accdb;DefaultDir=S:\path;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5 ` But I have read in other posts that this did not solve the problem. I will test it though. Do I just add `;mode=Read`?

Comment: Ok, look at this link, on how to change a DSN, I'd create your own DSN for this particular solution.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dn170482(v=vs.85).aspx  When setting up the connection, through ODBC Data source (From Other Sources) there is a read only option there.